# Specifiy which date is labelled first on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 
17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 
18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383
), class = "Date"), Return = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, -0.5, 0.2, 
4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, -0.5, 0.2, 4, 0.3, 0.4, -0.5, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, -0.5), Rating = c("1", "1", "NA", "5", "3", "NA", "3", 
"4", "4", "NA", "5", "5", "NA", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot the data with "Month" on the x-axis and "Return" on the y-axis.
First I make some adjustments to my data:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(Rating = fifelse(is.na(Rating),"NA",as.character(Rating)))

Data$Month <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Data$Month, format="%Y-%m") )
```

Then I use the following code:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=`Month`, y=`Return`, group=`Rating`, fill=`Rating`, color=`Rating`)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks ="6 months", date_labels = "%Y-%m")
```

Then I have some space between the y-axis and the lines of the graphs. I then run the following code that eliminates the space (included  `expand=c(0,0)`):

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=`Month`, y=`Return`, group=`Rating`, fill=`Rating`, color=`Rating`)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks ="6 months", date_labels = "%Y-%m", expand=c(0,0))
```

However, when I add  `expand=c(0,0)` on the x-axis the first date that is shown also changes and moves very close to the y-axis which I don't like. Now 2018-08 is the first month being on the x-axis. However, before it was 2018-12 which I prefer. How can I change that so I have 2018-12 again being the first month on the x-axis being labelled.

Comment: Does `scale_x_date(..., limits = c(desired_start, desired_end), ...)`, where *desired_start* etc. supply the desired values help?

Comment: Thanks, @I_O for the comment. Unfortunately, I get the following error: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. Although I use Data$Month <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Data$Month, format="%Y-%m") )

Comment: If you want specific breaks then IMHO you are better off with explicitly setting the breaks using e.g. `breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-12-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "6 months")`.

Comment: @stefan thank you for your help. So I add this to the line of scale_x_date(breaks =seq.Date(as.Date("2018-12-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "6 months")? When I do that I get the error: Error in seq.Date("2018-12-01" : 
  'from' must be object of "Date" . Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsI mentioned in my comment, if you want specific breaks then IMHO you are better off with explicitly setting the breaks using the `breaks` argument.

Moreover, be aware that you have convert character strings to dates using `as.Date`. From the error message you mentioned in your comment I would guess that you have missed that:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = `Month`, y = `Return`, group = `Rating`, fill = `Rating`, color = `Rating`)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-12-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "6 months"), 
               date_labels = "%Y-%m", expand = c(0.005, 0))
```

[image]